# Start function in background and save PID

Tags: shell, background-process, bash-functions

I have a script containing two functions. one function starts the other as a background process and returns that processes UID. This works well, as long as I don't want to put the PID into a dedicated variable. Once I try to assign the PID to a variable, the script hangs until the background operation finishes.

This behaviour can be demonstrated by the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo () {
    bar &   # start bar in background
    echo $! # return bars' PID
}

bar () {
    sleep 5 # some background operation
}

FOO=$(foo) # remember the PID of bar
echo $FOO  # expectation: should echo immediately
           # reality: echo after five seconds
```

So, my question is: How can I get the script to continue executing after starting the `bar` function, without waiting for `bar` to return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subshell started by `$(foo)` has to exit completely (along with any background processes), so that the main shell knows there's no further input coming to be captured by the command substitution. After all, `bar` could output something after the sleep.

But you could redirect the output of `bar` to `/dev/null`:

```
foo () { 
    bar > /dev/null &
    echo "$!"
}
```

Or (in Bash or ksh) nix the command substitution and run `bar` in the main shell:

```
foo() {
    typeset -n _pid=$1
    bar &
    _pid=$!
}
foo FOO
echo "$FOO"
```

(Or the equivalent with `eval` in standard `sh`.)